# PM2 installation not generating script

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, pm2

I need to deploy a *NodeJs* application following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04.

When installing *PM2* module and generating *pm2* daemon script `pm2 startup upstart`, no command is shown, normally it should display a command like this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u sammy --hp /home/sammy
```

*NodeJs* v0.10.48 (on *Ubuntu*-12)

Comment: Try to restart pm2 with `systemctl restart pm2` and run `pm2 startup upstart` you will aslo need to save the app with `pm2 save` before restarting.

Comment: when executing systemctl restart pm2, it display systemctl: command not found

Comment: Try to reinstall systemd `sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd`

Comment: systemd is not installed, i am using ubuntu 12.04, so the only system available is upstart

Comment: before restart don't forget to save app .As upstart is enabled in your OS then try to restart pm2 with `initctl restart pm2`

Comment: when executing initctl restart pm2, it displays unknown job pm2

Comment: Use `pm2 startup` it will automatically detect init system available and generate the startup script.

Comment: init system is upstart, and it generated a script successfully, but normally after this, i run the command pm2 startup upstart. it has to generate a command that i will run as superuser, but it didn't display it

Comment: Please follow this link http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/ , after `pm2 startup` you will not need to run `pm2 startup upstart` as sudo user as it will already be there in the script generate by above command. just run `pm2 save` and restart your system it will automatically restart PM2.